# Merging completable futures

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public class ProcessorService {
     @Autowired private AsyncService asyncService;

     public Void process() {
        List<CompletableFuture<List<MyEntity>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            futures.add(asyncService.getSomething());
        }

        List<MyEntity> flatList = sequence(futures); // compile error
     }

     private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture =
                CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
        return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
                futures.stream().
                        map(future -> future.join()).
                        collect(Collectors.<T>toList())
        );
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
Required type: List<MyEntity>
Provided: CompletableFuture<List<List<MyEntity>>>
```

How can I get a list that has all the elements from individual futures merged into one?

Comment: You are just missing the `join()` call: `sequence(futures).join()`. Note that if you always plan to join, there isn’t much value in doing the `allOf()` stuff – just keep the Stream collect operation and return that list from `sequence()`.

Comment: Side note: don’t pre-size the array when using `toArray`. Just use `futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])`. That’s simpler, more robust, and unintuitively, even more efficient, as analyzed in [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)